# Hosting with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, apache

I want to upload my first site in node. I have a hosting and domain bought. by default it comes with apache as web server.

Is there something I can configure using ftp to make it work with node, or should I communicate with the hosting provider to make it work with node?

Comment: does the host have node installed? if not can you install packages on your host?

Comment: I cannot check if it's installed. I cannot install anything. I only have access by ftp and to the control panel (Where it does not says anything).
Assuming it's installed can I try some how if a simple code run? how should I do?

Comment: assuming that its shared hosting, only your hosting provider - can - install things, you have virtual user privileges basic limited to your domain, i assume its not a VPS , if provider does offer node.js then you can't do anything about it.. Better purchase a VPS or dedicated server.